# Magento 2 add cart contents to email termplate

Tags: template, email-templates, abandoned-cart

Is there a way to add the contents of the users cart to an email template?  I would like to do this for the abandoned cart email and would rather not use a 3rd party extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build objects which you then pass through to email templates.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/283338/70343

If it's a custom template then it's going to be custom code passing the variables.